# How to get token value while sending post requests

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to extract the data from webpage after log in. To log in website, i can see the token (authenticity_token) in Form Data section. It seems, token   generating automatically.I am trying to get token values but no luck.Please anyone help me on this,how to get the token value while sending the post requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the response from the page then regex match for token.

Comment: In log in page, html content, authenticity_token not exist

Comment: You can verify the requirement of token by looking at post request. If it's required,  it is definitely going to be there. Typically token is provided in a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

token value is stored in the cookie file..check the cookie file and extract the value from it..
for example,a cookie file after login contain jsession ID=A01~xxxxxxx
where 'xxxxxxx' is the token value..extract this value..and post this value